# npm pdfjs creates corrupted PDF files

Tags: node.js, pdf, npm, pdf-generation, pdf.js

I am trying to create PDF files with the npm library pdfjs https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs . Once all the elements (paragraphs) of the file are append to the doc I create the file, but when opening it I have a message it says is corrupted.

When I use `doc.end()` to finish the document, says there is no function. So I used a promise and tried to use later on the information. But even when I get an object with all the data, I can't manage to make the .pdf file not corrupted.

This is the code I'm using:

```
const pdf = require('pdfjs')
const fs  = require('fs')

function createPDF(data, options){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var doc = new pdf.Document({ font: require('pdfjs/font/Helvetica') });
    var header = doc.header().table({ widths: [null, null], paddingBottom: 1*pdf.cm }).row()
    header.cell().image('/images/logo.png', { height: 2*pdf.cm })
    header.cell().text({ textAlign: 'right' })
    .add('Example.')
    .add('https://www.example.com', {
      link: 'https://www.example.com',
      underline: true,
      color: 0x569cd6
    })
    doc.footer()
    .pageNumber(async function(curr, total) { return curr + ' / ' + total }, { textAlign: 'center' });



    resolve(doc)

  });
}

var doc = createPDF();


doc.then(async (data) => {
  data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'))
  console.log(data);
  await data.end();
})
```

Log Data:

```
Document {
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes:
      WriteStream {
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        path: 'output.pdf',
        fd: null,
        flags: 'w',
        mode: 438,
        start: undefined,
        autoClose: true,
        pos: undefined,
        bytesWritten: 0 },
     pipesCount: 1,
     flowing: true,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: true,
     paused: false,
     emitClose: true,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events:
   { read: { [Function: bound onceWrapper] listener: [Function] },
     end: { [Function: bound onceWrapper] listener: [Function: onend] },
     data: [Function: ondata] },
  _eventsCount: 3,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  version: '1.6',
  info: { id: '34d7f55c-5961-4caf-9814-1902b98bee3c' },
  width: 595.296,
  height: 841.896,
  _nextObjectId: 4,
  _xref: PDFXref { objects: [], trailer: null },
  _reading: false,
  _length: 0,
  _pending:
   [ [Function],
     [ [Function], [Array], [Array], [Function] ],
     [Function],
     [Function],
     [Function],
     [Function],
     current: Promise { <pending> } ],
  defaultFont:
   AFMFont {
     _data:
      { fontName: 'Helvetica',
        fullName: 'Helvetica',
        familyName: 'Helvetica',
        italicAngle: 0,
        characterSet: 'ExtendedRoman',
        fontBBox: [Array],
        underlinePosition: -100,
        underlineThickness: 50,
        capHeight: 718,
        xHeight: 523,
        ascender: 718,
        descender: -207,
        kerning: [Object],
        widths: [Array] },
     lineGap: 231,
     parent: [Circular] },
  defaultFontSize: 11,
  defaultColor: [ 0, 0, 0 ],
  defaultLineHeight: 1.15,
  _fonts: { '/F1': { f: [Object], o: [Object] } },
  _xobjects: {},
  _pageFonts: {},
  _annotations: [],
  _aliases: AliasGenerator { nextId: { F: 2 }, blocked: Set {} },
  _mapping: WeakMap {},
  _currentContent: null,
  _contents: [],
  _contentObjCreator: null,
  _finalize: [],
  _template: null,
  _footer: null,
  _header: null,
  paddingTop: 20,
  paddingBottom: 20,
  paddingLeft: 20,
  paddingRight: 20,
  _cursor:
   Cursor {
     width: 555.296,
     height: 801.896,
     x: 20,
     startX: 20,
     y: 821.896,
     startY: 821.896,
     _bottom: 20,
     bottomOffset: 0 },
  _pages: [ toString: [Function] ],
  _pagesObj:
  PDFObject {
     id: 2,
     rev: 0,
     properties: PDFDictionary { dictionary: [Object] },
     reference: PDFReference { object: [Getter] },
     content: 'stream\n!!!Djz!WW3#D/OH9;Fa%r=BSfM#MB(Z!#knQ!$hOd@:O@tzzzz!!!!"zz!!)`D!!*\'"!!(J"z\'&psr`WC#h?J?20S8TbAzzzzzzz!!!!1A7]gl!!!
$f!!!"E@TZc:!!!&8!!!!5@T65m!!!&L!!!95B2hbr!!!&L!!!95E`>q(!!!&L!!!95A8Pjf!!!>`!!!"TB38;?!!!@>!!!!5CisT/!!!@R!!!!5D.R-s!!!@f!!!!E@V]q)!!!A5!
!!!5E`cIJ!!!AI!!!!5FCerq!!!A]!!!!-G\'.A,!!!Ai!!!"SGB@eG!!!CG!!!!5@rQI1!!!C[!!!!X@q]:]!!!D>!!!!MA7]glz!!!!@F&GLp+A#!h2DI3M2D$[90d\'qA@:O\'q
F(8WpARkc@zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz=BSfMz!!":;!!!O_!!\'IR@s)g8z!!!-%!!!!&!"&]:!#,DN!$2+b!%7h!!&=O5!\':0G!(?l[!)ESo!*K;.!+Q"B!,V^V!-\\Ej!.b-)!/g
i=!0mPQ!1s7e!3#t$!3uU6!5&<J!6,#^!71_r!8@M3!9F4H!:U!^!;cct!=&W7!>>JO!?V=g!@n1+!B:*D!C[#_!E&r$!FPq@!H%p\\!IOp#!K-uA!La%_!N?+)!P&6I!QbAi!SIM4
!U0XU!Vuj"!Xo,E!Z_=h!\\XU7!^Ql\\!`T5,!bVRS!dXp$!fd>L!hoat!k&0H!m:Yq!oO.G!qcWq!t,2H"!Iau"#pBM"&B#&"(hXU"+C?0"-s%`"0Ma;"31Mm"5j:J"8N\'(";:n\
\">\'a<"@rYq"ChRS"F^K4"I]Il"L\\HO"OdM4"RlQn"UtVT"Y0a;"\\Al""_S!_"bm2H"f;I2"iUYq"m#p]"pP8I"t\'U6#"Sr$#&4?h#)ibW#-S6H#13Y8#5&3+#8mas#<`;f#@R
jZ#DNJO#HS0F#LWk=#P\\Q4#Tj=-#Y#)\'#]9p"#aPar#egSm#j2Kj#nRCh#s&Ag$"O?f$\',Cg$+^Gh$0;Kj$5!Um$9\\_q$>Kp!$CD1\'$H3A-$M+W5$R,s=$W.:G$\\/VP$a:#[
$fMKh$k`su$ptG.%!;u=%&XNL%+u\'\\%1Nan%6tA+%<N&>%B0fS%GhQh%MK=)%S7.@%Y"tX%^lkq%dji6%j_`P%pfcm&!da4&\'kdQ&.&mp&47";&:P1[&@iA(&G6VK&MXkn&T&,=
&ZQGb&a0i4&ge5[&nDW.&u-)W\'&sW-\'-e/X\'4V].\';Q;\\\'BKo4\'IOSd\'P\\>?\'Wi(p\'^uhM\'f6Y+\'mLI_\'tk@?(\'>=!(.f9X(696:(=j8t(EF;X(M+D>(TnS&(\\
\\ac(dJpL(lB06(tBK")\'Bec)/C+P)7LL>)?^s.)GqDs)P.kd)XJCW)`o!K)i>T?)ql85*%Dq+*.&[#*6]Dq*?H4k*H3$e*Q&oa*Yoe^*bla\\*ki][*to_[+))g]+28o_+;H"b+D
`0f+N,Dl+WMXr+a"s%+jM8.+t"R7,(_#B,2FIN,<-o[,EsFi,Ocs#,Y]P3,c`3E,mbkW-"nTk--%>+-7:-A-ANqW-Klfo-V5\\3-`\\WM-k.Rh-ugZ0.+B[M.6&bl.@hp7.KV(W.VL
<$.aKUH.lJnl/"J3</-RRb/8d#5/CuH^/O:t3/ZUJ^/f$\'5/qP^b0((A<03U#k0?5aF0JtP#0VgDW0bQ350nM-k1%I(L11N)/1=S)h1Ia0M1Uo721b1Co1nHPV2%qiA22=\'+2>oE
l2KC^Y2X*.G2deS72qL#\'3)DSn364)`3C5`U3P7BJ3]9$@3jLg84"WO04/tC+4=<7&4JY+"4X*$t4eY$s4s3$s5+k*t59W7"5GCC%5U/O)5c-g05q,*76**B?681`H6FB/S6TRS_6
bl(l6q9Y&7*\\4679)dF7G^KX7V>2k7dro*7sdbA8-MOW8<HHp8KCB48Z>;N8iK@j9#O@292eKP9B&Vp9QEh<9`e$]9p8<,:*iYQ::F"!:J"?G:Yehp:iT=D;$Klo;4CGF;DD\'s;T
D]L;dWJ\';ta0W<0(#5<@Cji<PhcI<a8\\)<qfZ`=-?YC=>*d)=Nahc=_V$K=pJ53>,GKr>=Db]>NK*I>_ZM7>pip&?--Ck?>Nr]?OpLP?aF,D?rpa9@/OG/@A73\'@S(%!@dmkpA!
^]kA3a[iAEdYgAWgWfAj\'ahB\'<kjB9QumBKp0rB^BG#Bprc+C.N*3CA2L>CSttJCfbGVD$XudD7ONsDJO..D]WhADp`MSE/&>iEB8*)EU\\!AEi*mYF\'WjsF;/h9FNekUFbOtsG
!:)=G5-8^GI)N+G]%cMGq+)rH09KCHDPrkHXhE>Hm*lgI,TK>IA))jIU[cCIj9GrJ)u2NJ>e#+JSTh]JhVe>K(O[sK=Z^VKRea9Kh$itL(8rYL=_2BLS\'A*LhV[jM)1!VM>iBCMTU
i2MjB;!N+7ghNA6E[NW5#NNm<\\DO.MF;OD^02O["u,OqEk\'P2ha#PI?\\uP_t^tQ!]fuQ8Fo"QO9(%Qf+6)R(/P0R?3j7RV8/?RmNUJS/e&USG/RbS^O)pT!"\\+T8T?<TP:(OTg
tfbU*cV#UB[K:UZS@QUrT;kV5^=1VMh>MVf&EjW)BS4WAgfUWZ8%"Wrf>EX6H]jXO+(;XgkMcY+`$7YD]UbY][28Z!aifZ:hL?ZT,:oZmE)L[1fs*[K3g^[d^b>\\)=c!\\C%iZ\\\
\bp>]!].&];N:b]UQSL]oTl7^4a6#^O!Zf^i7*U_.UUE_I(17_cXh+`)4Iu`Cn1k`^[tca$Ib\\a?@VWaZ@PSauIPQb;RPPbVdVPbr*bRc8NtVcSs1[coKIad6,gjdQc0rdmV[)e4J
05eP=ZBelC;Rf3HqcfOWXufkf@3g323IgOS&_gkso!h3Qn;hP/mVhlkrri4\\);iQU:[inNL\'j6PcIjS\\+mjpgI=k9&ldkVDA7ksjpal<EQ8lYu1em"Xm>m@<Smm^2FJn\'(9\'n
E\'1\\nc/0=o,7.toJH3Wohb><p20O#pPS_`po+!Jq8`>5qWIa"r!3.er@.]Vr_*7Gs)%f9A7]glz!!!!O8OYuh2DI3M2D$[90d&kqAmoguF<FIO66JX6Ci=H:+B*5f@q?c7+ELFN6
3$uczzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz=BSfMz!!$Jr!!\'K^!!!ki=BSfMzz!)NXqzD.R-sz!!!!"zzzzz!!!!#=BSfMz!!!"j!!!"p!!!"S=BSfMz!!$r3!!#"O!!!+_F(o80z6W-l+A7]glz
!!!!N;IsHOEb0,uAKY#fATqj+B-9Q[DIdI\'Bl@l3Bl5%b77/1U0f_-M/M\\n4zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz=BSfMz!!)`D!!*\'"!!(J"FCf]=z6Z6phEbT0"F<F.mFCfK1@<?4%DII
?(6Z6dZEZd_fDKB`:FD5l7/0H]%0KB+5F(R3`z!!*Kr!!!2[s8V[;!!!7g!!)tYs8Vtis8W%l!!!,U!!\'fW~>\nendstream\n' },
  _currentColorSpace: '/CS1',
  _doc: [Circular],
  _parent: [Circular],
  _ended: false,
  _current:
   Footer {
     _doc: [Circular],
     _parent: [Circular],
     _cursor:
      ClonedCursor {
        width: 555.296,
        height: 801.896,
        bottomOffset: 0,
        startX: 20,
        startY: 821.896,
        _root: [Object] },
     _ended: false,
     _current: null,
     _pending:
      [ [Function],
        [Array],
        [Function],
        [Function],
        [Function],
        [Function],
        current: [Object] ],
     _objects: [],
     _pageNumbers: [] } }
```

It looks like the content is there but can't manage to get it. And whe `await data.end();` is run, it show the next error log show:

```
TypeError: Invalid value used as weak map key TypeError: Invalid value used as weak map key
    at WeakMap.set (native)
    at Document._useXObject (/home/developer1/Projects/bfreit_website/node_modules/pdfjs/lib/document.js:255:21)
    at module.exports (/home/developer1/Projects/bfreit_website/node_modules/pdfjs/lib/image/render.js:16:23)
    at _pending.push (/home/developer1/Projects/bfreit_website/node_modules/pdfjs/lib/fragment.js:143:30)
    at Document._next (/home/developer1/Projects/bfreit_website/node_modules/pdfjs/lib/document.js:169:36)
    at _pending.current.next.then (/home/developer1/Projects/bfreit_website/node_modules/pdfjs/lib/document.js:172:19)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

The expected output is a correct .pdf file. But even when my output is a .pdf file, it is corrupted.

```
Unable to open document “file:///home/developer1/Projects/pdf/output.pdf”.
Error when trying to open the file:
PDF document is damaged
```

If you can help me either solving this, or with a library of your knowledge that it works will be bomb.

Comment: are you using camelcaseKeys().?

Comment: Sorry i believe don't understand your question. I'm not using camel case. Where do I should use camel case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could not found a solution for the pdfjs library. But I found a library that worked better in my project pdfkit `npm i -S pdfkit`. It is really easy to work with.
Short Example:

```
const pdf = require('pdfkit');
const fs = require('fs');
const doc = new pdf();

doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/my/path'));
doc.fontSize(10).text('Fontsize 10')
doc
      .fontSize(18)
      .text('Font Size 18 aligned right', {align: 'right'});
doc.moveDown();
doc.fontSize(14).text('Font size 14 aligned center',{align:'center' })
doc.end();
```